# SQLAlchemy One to Many relationship mapping/joining error

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to create a relationship between speaker and records.
A speaker can have multiple records

but the error below was shown:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Class 
>   does not have a mapped column named 'speaker_id'

Speaker Model:

```
class Speaker(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'speakers'
    id       = db.Column(db.Integer,     primary_key=True)
    cin      = db.Column(db.String(8),  unique = True)
    nom      = db.Column(db.String(64))
    prenom   = db.Column(db.String(64))
    adresse  = db.Column(db.String(120))
    datedn   = db.Column(db.String(20)) 
    genre    = db.Column(db.String(64))
    phone    = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    profession = db.Column(db.String(120))
    records  = db.relationship('Record', backref="owner", primaryjoin="Speaker.id==Record.speaker_id")
    created  = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

Record Model:

```
class Record(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'record'
    id       = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    path     = db.Column(db.String(500))
    created  = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    speaker_id = db.column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('speakers.id'))
```

I Have tried the relationship without `primaryjoin` but I had this error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition
>   between parent/child tables on relationship Speaker.records - there
>   are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing
>   columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or
>   specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of a typo, but something that pops up every now and then: the c in "column" has to be capitalized in 6th line of the Record class (on the speaker id line).